# Scroll to section navigation issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, scroll

I am building a single page website and need a 'scroll to section navigation', I'm using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/606/) as a basic template. As you can see it works like a charm, however for some reason on my website it doesn't seem to work, I have pasted a couple of important code snippets below

```
<!-- THIS IS A SECTION -->

<section id="about" data-anchor="about">
  <div id="about-wrap">
    <h1>I'm a really cool title about<br>Small Space Living</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ...esse.</p>
    <a class="link" href=""><span>Learn More</span></a>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- THIS IS MY NAVIGATION -->

<div class="navbar pull-right">
  <ul class="navi">
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="about">About Us<hr></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="solutions">Solutions<hr></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="contact">Contact Us<hr></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- THIS IS MY JQUERY -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
$('navi a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint  = $('section[data-anchor="'+scrollAnchor+'"]').offset().top -10;

   $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: scrollPoint
   }, 500);

   return false;

})

$(window).scroll(function() {

});

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {

        $('nav').addClass('fixed');

    } else {

        $('navi').removeClass('fixed');

    }

});
});//]]>  
});
</script>
```

there is a fair amount of css but I can't imagine it being a style problem as the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/606/) has zero style and still works.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can only guess, but I'd say you probably aren't wrapping your code in an onload on your website.  JSfiddle does that for you automagically.

Comment: I see, you mean the jquery code am I right? Do you know what that looks like exactly, I'm dusting up on my Jquery as we speak but am still quite the novice! Thanks for the help @JamesKorden

Comment: I've added an answer with an example in.  The example of `$(document).ready(function(){` is just as valid, but I wanted to show a different way for the hell of it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a file with the following in it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {

$('nav a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint  = $('section[data-anchor="'+scrollAnchor+'"]').offset().top -10;

   $('body,html').animate({
       scrollTop: scrollPoint
   }, 500);

   return false;

})

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {

        $('nav').addClass('fixed');

    } else {

        $('navi').removeClass('fixed');

    }
});

}
</script>
<header></header>

<nav>

    <a href="#" data-scroll="top">TOP</a>

    <a href="#" data-scroll="news">NEWS</a>

    <a href="#" data-scroll="products">PRODUCTS</a>

    <a href="#" data-scroll="contact">CONTACT</a>

</nav>



    <section id="top" data-anchor="top">

        <h4>TOP</h4>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>

    </section>

    <section id="news" data-anchor="news">

        <h4>NEWS</h4>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>

    </section>

    <section id="products" data-anchor="products">

        <h4>PRODUCTS</h4>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>

    </section>

    <section id="contact" data-anchor="contact">

        <h4>CONTACT</h4>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel. Aliquam eu nulla eros, et tincidunt felis. Pellentesque congue sodales eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla suscipit nulla vel nisi fermentum ultricies. Integer ligula elit, gravida ac pretium nec, eleifend ultrices purus. Duis cursus orci et urna accumsan tempor. Nunc mattis tincidunt nulla, id porta velit sollicitudin blandit.</p>

            <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris dictum nisl eget lorem pulvinar sit amet bibendum nunc scelerisque. Suspendisse ac libero magna, at imperdiet leo. Pellentesque vulputate venenatis vestibulum. Aenean varius turpis quis sem adipiscing volutpat. Fusce scelerisque iaculis augue, eget fringilla velit mattis nec. Maecenas sagittis dolor eget felis cursus imperdiet. Morbi ut dui libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sit amet mi ac diam semper hendrerit a id tellus. Morbi accumsan magna sit amet velit ultricies ut dapibus justo rutrum. Ut et ante dui, vel pellentesque velit.</p>

    </section>
```

Then I saved it as index.html.  Opened it, and it worked.

The main problem you had was `$('navi a')` which I changed to '$('nav a')`.  I think a tiny typo got you.

**Edit**
I feel I should explain a little better.  You should not use `.navi`, as that refers to the class of an object: .  You shouldn't use `#navi` as that refers to the id of an object: .  Using `navi` refers to a  object.  Since you wanted to refer to a  tag, we use `$('nav')`.  Hope this clarifies a little.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks James really appreciate all the time and effort you put into helping me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/609/

It works good there. Is it possible that you have some other js error that block this script?

@EDIT: Try this code: you miss a point in class definition!! `$('.navi a')`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navi a').on('click', function() {

var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
    scrollPoint  = $('section[data-anchor="'+scrollAnchor+'"]').offset().top -10;

$('body,html').animate({
   scrollTop: scrollPoint
}, 500);

return false;

});
});
```

If you don't want any animation you can use this easy anchor with a:

```
<nav>

<a href="#top">TOP</a>

<a href="#news">NEWS</a>

<a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a>

<a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>

</nav>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/608/

Comment: Thanks @Emanuele Parisio we now have the website navigating to specific sections, however it's just appearing at the section and NOT scrolling down. I can't see anything in the jquery that would cause this, I did notice however that your jsfiddle had no jquery? Thanks again. Great help so far

Comment: I see what you mean now, its not animated because its a simple <a> anchor. In answer to your question there is no other js script that is blocking the feature in question. Strange don't you think? Would it help at all if your saw my website and had a quick look at the source code?

Comment: If you have a link i can look at it on live.
The problem is not the script because there works great. So the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: sure, here is a link to the site itself http://smallspaceliving.co.uk Thanks a bunch @Emanuele Parisio really appreciate the help. By the way I have tried removing the script which fiddles with the size of the header and the scroll feature still doesn't seem to work ..

Comment: Found it probably, i can't debug the js becouse it's not in a separate file but probably you don't initialize the script.
Try to put the script in:
`$(document).ready(function(){
//your code
});`

Comment: Thanks @Emanuele Parisio still doesn't seem to want to play nice for some reason? I have added the amended script in the original question above, does that look right to you?